# Method naming GetX by multiple parameters

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I'm designing a factory class and was wondering what an acceptable method naming convention is for retrieving a collection of objects based on varying parameters.

Example:

Get all objects from my data source (#1 no parameters):

```
public GetAll(){...}
```

Get all objects with matching name (#2 name parameter):

```
public GetByName(string name){..}
```

Get all objects with matching 'another property' (#3 'another property' parameter):

```
public GetByAnotherProperty(string anotherProperty){...}
```

Now, where I'm running into trouble is when I want to add a get method that takes two or more properties:

Get all objects with matching name and 'another property' (#4 two parameters):

a few attempts of mine:

```
public GetByNameAndAnotherProperty(string name, string anotherProperty){...}
public GetByNameByAnotherProperty(string name, string anotherProperty){...}
public Get(string name, string anotherProperty){...}
```

I can see the first two approaches becoming very cumbersome once I have more than two or three parameters. Example:

```
public GetByNameByPropertyXByPropertyYByPropertyZ(string name, etc.){...}
```

Is there a better way to do this? How would one design a flexible class that takes an arbitrary amount of parameters and keep the naming convention clean and concise?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it seems to me you are looking forthis:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public FooClass GetByProperties(params string[] list)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how would I distinguish whether the item in the list is property A or B?

Comment: You cant. If you have to distinguish them, create a class that will represent method's input params. This approach is also recommended if you have more than 5 input params. So, it would look like this: public FooClass GetByProperties(ParamClass parameters);

Comment: I settled on optional / named parameters to minimize the need for method overloading. [Technique used.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff467291.aspx) Thanks for your help.